# Unit testing using a CSV for arguments

Tags: python

I am testing a function and have written unit tests to assert if the result matches what I expect when I input certain arguments into the function.

Instead of writing many unit tests, I want to read a csv file that has, row by row, all the possible permutations of arguments and an expected result. The test should loop through each row of arguments, compare expected result with actual result and give me the pass or fail.

I am very new to python and testing with python.

Comment: You don’t appear to have a question. If you don’t have code either, please note that StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Also don’t request recommendations for e.g. testing libraries, because requesting libraries is specifically off-topic. Maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Python comes with a built-in [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) module you may be able to use.